# App.config returns null

Tags: c#, null, app-config

There are a lot of questions like this and I've checked them out all.

Firstly, I checked the `app.config`'s path using

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
```

to make sure code looking for the right `app.config` file.

After making sure of that, I still dont know why `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];` is returning null. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="BaseURL" value="blabla" />
</appSettings>
```

**Answer Edit:** Next time do not be like me and overwork your brain. You may forget you are working at a Virtual Machine, not at your desktop. In short, this is another "looking at the wrong place" question.

Comment: Make sure you have correct format:

<appSettings>
    <add key="BaseURL" value="MyURL"/>
</appSettings>

Comment: Sorry for not writing that but the code is exactly like this in app.config file

Comment: Put a break point in code at this line.. ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];  Hover over appsettings and tell us what you see.

Comment: `System.Configuration.KeyValueInternalCollection`. `AllKeys {string[0]} `when I expand that along with other fields.

Comment: Post your edit as an answer and give it a check mark. This will help others who find your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

Use WebConfigurationManager instead of using ConfigurationManager

Example :

Place below code in your web.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="BaseURL" value="blabla" />
</appSettings>
```

and

To get the value use the WebConfigurationManager like below

```
string base_url= WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"].ToString();
```